# C# internal == public C++

Tags: c#, c++

Is the C++ `public` keyword **exactly** equivalent to `internal` keyword in C#?

As far as I understand, `public` in C++ means "can be used everywhere within the compilation unit".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not exactly equivalent.  For starters, a C++ "compilation unit" isn't equivalent to a .NET assembly.

Next, in C++ there is an additional concept, "linkage", which determines whether a type can be used outside the compilation unit.  Whether the same header file is included in other compilation units also affects visibility.

Answer (score 5):

C++ has no concept of an assembly.
Therefore, there is no equivalent in C++ of the difference between C#'s `public` and `internal`.

Unlike C#'s `internal` modifier, `public` members in C++ can be used in other projects.

Comment: What's a "public class in C++"?  C++ doesn't apply access modifiers to types in namespace scope.  Furthermore, it's really only safe to use pure abstract classes across module boundaries, since `dllexport` tends to cause ODR violations.

Comment: Sorry; fixed.  I'm not used to C++.